# Filter fonts based on script support [Western, arabic, Greek, ...] in native C# (not P/Invoke)

Tags: c#, asp.net, fonts, filter

I am trying to fill drop down box with font family names and I have a lot of fonts almost 600 and I want to reduce this number based on the user interface for example when the interface is LTR (western) English or french for example I would need to load just the fonts that support those scripts nothing more

right now I am doing this:

```
InstalledFontCollection c = new InstalledFontCollection();

FontFamily[] fontF = c.Families;

return fontF.Select(i => i.GetName(0)).ToArray();
```

when trying to change the language identifier in `GetName` method with other value I end up with the same amount of result

I have the values from Winnt.h header file which can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mingw-org-wsl/ci/master/tree/include/winnt.h)

I am using asp.net C# 4.5
what I am looking for is native C# solution without using P/Invoke or at least that would be my last fallback solution